# Having a error TS5011 TypeScript when i compile

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors, typescript-typings

My Code at say.ts file:

```
function say(person) {
    return "Hello" + person;
}

var user = "Gabriel Lemos";

console.log(say(user));
```

When i try to compile it withi

> tsc say.ts

I have the error: path\say.js(1,1): error TS5011: Emit Error: Failure to record the file..

Comment: Are you sure you're able to write to `path`?

Comment: i think i'm, the .ts file was created whitout any trouble.

Comment: It looks like the "Emit Error" message only exists in TypeScript older than 1.5.0, which is 3 years old.  You might try a newer version of TypeScript to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: i just installed the typescript, node and npm right now

Comment: That was no permition to write.